# Unable to contact the server for Certificate Revocation List (CRL) in WCF mutual SSL authentication

Tags: wcf, ssl, ssl-certificate

I am trying to build an application in WCF which will work through a mutual SSL authentication. The server side SSL certificate works fine but when the service trying to authenticate the client, it fails to read the CRL. It is showing the following message -

> **HTTP Error 403.13 - Forbidden, Your client certificate was revoked, or the revocation status could not be determined**

However as far as I know it can be happen when-
1. If a CRL server is unreachable.
2. If the IIS is unable to access the Internet.

But the CRL distribution point address is reachable, I can download the CRL by copy pasting the address in the browser. And the IIS is working fine.

So there is some other problem that is unknown to me. Can anybody here to help me about the issue. Is there any way to load the CRL from any local directory?

Answer (score 0):

(Only for information)

Try the following : run -> certutil -url [your_certificate_path] . Check CRLs (From CDP).

This is used for checkin if the CDP is really reachable...

Check Certification Path if there is some issue if Intermediate and Root Cert Authority

Answer (score 0):

Your CRL might also be outdated. Field nextUpdate is in the past.